# jquery fadeout darkens layer behind it

Tags: jquery, css

Pretty simple premise. I've got a floating image and I want to reveal the image behind it. Works fine in chrome, but not in FF 11.

```
$("#floater").fadeOut("slow");  

<div id="bg-image">
 <img id="bg-photo" class="photo" src="../images/blackberry.jpg" alt=""/>        
 <img id="floater" class="floater" src="../images/blackberry_flash.jpg"  alt="" />
</div>

#bg-image .photo 
{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1284px;
}

#container {
     width:100%;
     min-width:950px;
     margin-top:-13px;
}


#floater {
    position:fixed; 
    z-index:4;
    top:200px;
    left:200px;
}
```

Instead of just fading to reveal the image at z-index 0, it fades the area to black. My background is white and there's no other css that could interfere really.

Comment: I have tested in FF12 and chrome it's working fine and here is the fiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/HYNFV/2/

Comment: It seems to be working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/yg7TT/ so there must be something else going on in your actual page.

Comment: @jfriend00 Neither of those fiddles work properly in FF11. Fades to black. Fine in chrome still. Anyone? I'm about to ditch jquery and do it manually because i'm sick of how it never works as expected.

Comment: @FlavorScape - this has nothing to do with jQuery.  jQuery is just doing something very simple here.  It's either browser issue or a CSS issue.  FYI, my jsFiddle works fine in FF11 for me.

Comment: According to the bug, it sounds like it may be specific to some video drivers which might be why it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a firefox bug. It's been known since version 10 with hardware acceleration. Wonder why they didn't roll the fix into 11.

The fix: add white to the background of the actual div (not a parent)
http://weblog.scanyours.com/2011/01/05/howto-solving-the-firefox-opacity-bug/

The original bug:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=723524